# Dark mode button only works on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, responsive, darkmode

i setup the navbar to be responsive, but now the dark mode button only works on the mobile screen,

this the html,css and js respectively

```
    <nav>
      <ul class="sidebar">
        <li onclick=hideSidebar()><a href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="26" viewBox="0 96 960 960" width="26"><path d="m249 849-42-42 231-231-231-231 42-42 231 231 231-231 42 42-231 231 231 231-42 42-231-231-231 231Z"/></svg></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
        <li class='important'><a href="#">Get Started</a></li>
        <li><div class="btn">
          <div class="btn__indicator">
            <div class="btn__icon-container">
              <i class="btn__icon fa-solid fa-sun fa-moon"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li class="active hideOneMobile"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li class="hideOnMobile"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="hideOnMobile"><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
        <li class='important hideOnMobile'><a href="#">Get Started</a></li>
        <li class="hideOnMobile"><div class="btn">
          <div class="btn__indicator">
            <div class="btn__icon-container">
              <i class="btn__icon fa-solid fa-sun fa-moon"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div></li>
        <li class="menu-button" onclick=showSidebar()><a href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="26" viewBox="0 96 960 960" width="26"><path d="M120 816v-60h720v60H120Zm0-210v-60h720v60H120Zm0-210v-60h720v60H120Z"/></svg></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul {
  visibility: unset;
  opacity: 1;
  background: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: unset;
  height: auto;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateX(0);
  width:100%;
  transition: all .3s;
} 
nav ul li a {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0 1em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; 
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
  box-shadow: -10px 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  z-index: 1000;
  
}
.sidebar li{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem;
}
.sidebar .important{
  width: 8rem;
  margin-left: 1.8rem;
}
.sidebar .btn {
  margin-left: 0.8rem;
}
.sidebar a{
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-button{
  display: none;
}
@media(max-width: 800px){
  .hideOnMobile {
    display: none;
  }
  .active {
    display: none;
  }
  .sidebar .active{
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-button{
    display: block;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 400px){
  .sidebar{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul {
  visibility: unset;
  opacity: 1;
  background: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: unset;
  height: auto;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateX(0);
  width:100%;
  transition: all .3s;
} 
nav ul li a {
  color: var(--primary-color);
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0 1em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; 
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
  box-shadow: -10px 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  z-index: 1000;
  
}
.sidebar li{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem;
}
.sidebar .important{
  width: 8rem;
  margin-left: 1.8rem;
}
.sidebar .btn {
  margin-left: 0.8rem;
}
.sidebar a{
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-button{
  display: none;
}
@media(max-width: 800px){
  .hideOnMobile {
    display: none;
  }
  .active {
    display: none;
  }
  .sidebar .active{
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-button{
    display: block;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 400px){
  .sidebar{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
  const isDarkMode = body.classList.contains('dark-mode');
  localStorage.setItem('dark-mode', JSON.stringify(isDarkMode));
  console.log(isDarkMode);
  // Toggle the spin animation class
  icon.classList.add('animated');
  setTimeout(() => {
    icon.classList.remove('animated');
  }, 500);
  if (isDarkMode) {
    icon.classList.remove('fa-sun');
    icon.classList.add('fa-moon');
    articleTitles.forEach(title => {
      title.classList.add('dark-mode');
    });
    articleAuthor.classList.add('dark-mode');
  } else {
    icon.classList.remove('fa-moon');
    icon.classList.add('fa-sun');
    articleTitles.forEach(title => {
      title.classList.remove('dark-mode');
    });
    articleAuthor.classList.remove('dark-mode');
  }
});
```

tried changing btn by hideOnMobile in the js code but it did not work, think the problem is with the "hideOnMobile" because with the media query is dissapears so everything works nice

Comment: Are you sure you've posted the relevant parts of your code? `btn` is undefined. I'm guessing it should be `const btn = document.querySelector(".btn")`. Also, when on mobile, a function named `showSidebar` is called, but it's not in your posted code. And the two CSS blocks seem to be almost identical (with the second one having an extra newline at the very end). There also seem to be references to elements not present in the code (`articleTitles`). Please make a minimal reproducible example, so that we can offer better suggestions.

Comment: Can you please host your [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code on a runnable code-hosting platform such as SO's own [Code Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), [CodePen](http://codepen.io/), or [any other testing pen](https://alternativeto.net/software/codepen/?license=opensource)?